# Automate the login on Google using an AWS Lambda function

Tags: selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I want to automate the login on Google using an AWS Lambda function, but I have hit a stone wall. I would appreciate it if someone could help me with either of these issues:

1º) Deploying undetected-chromedriver on AWS Lambda: After familiarizing myself with the framework and successfully running my code locally, I am unable to deploy it in my Lambda function. I don’t find information on how to do it. It would be my first option.

2º) As an alternative to point 1, I am trying to use Selenium with the --user-data-dir flag. When adding this driver option, my script fails, and I get the following error:

> Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
> (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

Below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Credenciales
platform_cred = {
    'user' : "my-mail@gmail.com",
    'password' : "password1234"
}


# Obtener credenciales
user = platform_cred['user']
password = platform_cred['password']

try:
    #Página de login
    url_login =  'https://accounts.google.com/v3/signin/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ifkv=ARZ0qKKlHmWPmUjrIyhEKyPF-fVgRf_dT_ACqQpf14q_v8u9SLNqLyt4n8q5vlR6qNka2j1kEVNiIA&rip=1&sacu=1&service=mail&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin&dsh=S-1459547155%3A1711711347417853&theme=mn&ddm=0'

    # Opciones de navegación
    options = Options()
    service = webdriver.ChromeService("C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe")
    options.binary_location = 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'
    options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    
    options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Jose A\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
    options.add_argument('profile-directory=Profile 3')

    # Driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)

    driver.get(url_login)

    # Login to account.google.com

    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#identifierId')))
    element.send_keys(user)
    
    # Pulsamos el boton "Ver todos los envíos"
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="identifierNext"]/div/button/span')))
    element.click()
    
    element_password = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')))
    element_password.send_keys(password)

    element_next = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="passwordNext"]/div/button/span')))
    element_next.click()
    
except WebDriverException as e:
    print(e)
```

Any assistance or guidance on resolving these issues would be immensely valuable to me. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

you can use google api key in your lambda function..you can get this key in google console

Comment: Sorry.  That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.  I need to get access without using API or key management.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).